# Firestore how to query posts collection for trending documents or should I use data aggregation

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a trending page on my application. I want trending posts to be based on how many likes the post has and how recent the post is. The more recent with more likes will get it to be listed first. I want something like this:

```
let startDate = moment();
startDate.subtract(3, "days");
snapshot = await db
  .collection("/vents/")
  .where("server_timestamp", ">", startDate.valueOf())
  .orderBy("like_counter")
  .limit(10)
  .get();
```

This obviously does not work because you can only orderBy the same field as the where clause. Does anybody know how to do this? If I have to use data aggregation to create a trending property on posts, I could do that but it would be a lot of code and would kind of suck to write all that out.

If I have to use data aggregation here is roughly how I would do it.
On each comment and like in the database, I would set up a listener to increase or decrease the trending attribute based on the new like or comment received and how old the post was. I would also need a pubscheduler to go through all posts and update them at least once a day to update the trending score attribute even if the post has not received a like or comment. I could also pull the top 20 trending posts once a day instead of all the posts and just update those as likely every other post in the database that is not trending would not likely need updating.

Please let me know your thoughts on if I should use data aggregation for this, or if I should build out my query.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code you are write you need to orderBy the same field as the where clause, but if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=) your first ordering must be on the same field, the tricky thing is that you can use more that one orderBy. An example of what I am saying could be:

```js
let startDate = moment();
startDate.subtract(3, "days");
snapshot = await db
  .collection("/vents/")
  .where("server_timestamp", ">", startDate.valueOf())
  .orderBy("server_timestamp")
  .orderBy("like_counter")
  .limit(10)
  .get();
```

I use [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) documentation to get to the code that I am sharing with you.